# Gallery onClick for previous/next image

Tags: android, gallery, onitemclick

I have a gallery with bunch of images. I'm able to perform onItemClick for one image. But I want to add left/right buttons to get the pervious/next image. How can I do that? Below is the code for onItemClick

```
@Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                                int position, long arg3) {

            ModelGallery model = (ModelGallery) mListView.getItemAtPosition(position);

            Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), GalleryActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
```

Here's the activity class. Loading the image from the URL passed from the Fragment class.

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.gallery);

    final ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.full_image);

    final String imageUrl = getIntent().getStringExtra("imageURL");

    Ion.with(imageView)
            .placeholder(R.drawable.ic_loading)
            .error(R.drawable.ic_error)
            .load(imageUrl);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

here are some links which will help you to solve your problem.

http://codetheory.in/android-image-slideshow-using-viewpager-pageradapter/

as gallary class get depricated : (Ref : http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Gallery.html ) you have to you horizontal-scrollview with view pager class (Ref : http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/HorizontalScrollView.html) (Ref : http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html)

And one more thing that you have to intent while list of URLs of images in second activity. not just one URL of image. hope it will help you.

Comment: So, I have to send the URLs of all the images with the intent and not just one image. Is that correct?

Comment: ya, because you wanna scroll all image in another activity. so you will need all url in putting viewpager.